# Need help, simple sheet code

Tags: excel

Current problem:
I need get data if(A:A142=1), same row B will be pasted into C.

Thanks for your help already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a simple loop:

```
Sub Henri()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A142")

    For Each r In A
        With r
            If .Value = 1 Then .Offset(0, 1).Copy .Offset(0, 2)
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not well explained but wouldn't pasting this formula

```
 = if(A1=1,B1,0)
```

from C1 down to C142 give the result you need?

Comment: Thought that might do the trick, but My B Column has names on it and the value of A Columns change betveen 1-5, I'm trying to impot the names from the B Column  into C. Your Formula = if(A1=1,B1,0) , Gave me Number 0 instead of Name. So is the formula missing something?   appreciated all the help you give :)